# How to corect the code it prints all symbols in a way that , in one dataframe ,and without any NaN or zeros?

Tags: python, dataframe, nan

Would you please correct the code, it prints all the symbols as well as without any ***NaN or zeros*** like?

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import yfinance as yf
start = datetime.datetime(2015, 10, 1)
end = datetime.datetime.now()
symbols = ['BTC-USD', 'ETH-USD', '^GSPC']
df = pd.DataFrame()

for i in symbols:
 data = yf.download(i, start=None, end=None, period="max", interval="1mo")
df[i] = data['Adj Close'].pct_change()
df = df.fillna(method='ffill')
```

The current output is:

[image]

Comment: please clarify your question. Are you looking to drop the nans rows? replace it with another value?

Comment: Sorry for not being clarify. Not only drop the nans rows, also, I want to correct the code in a way that it automatically detect the dates between the inputs(GOOG, ETH, etc).In other words, I don't want to have to edit NaNs, or dates or any thing.

Comment: Or, for example, the code warns me :the date you input is out of range for example GOOG.So, I correct the start  date in a way that there is no NaNs or any gaps between those.